# update all minimums in list to the next minimum

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

How do i increment numbers in a python list such that only the current minimums in that list are updated.
For example:

```
a = [15,15,14,12,10,10,10]
```

I have a number `x=12`
I need to optimally allocate it to this array such that the maximal is minimum, ie, first I give 2,2,2 to each 10 then 2,2,2 to any 3 12s. And my final list looks like this:

```
a = [15,15,14,14,14,14,12]
```

Comment: If you give 2,2,2 to each 10 and then 2,2,2 to any 3 12s you should be left with a = [15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 14, 12]. How are you ending up with a 10 in the list?

Comment: x=0 and a = [15,15,14,14,14,14,10] @sureshvv

Comment: The sum of your old list is 86, the sum of your updated list is only 96, not 98, like it should be if you've added 12 to it.

Comment: @PM2Ring I forgot to rewrite the 10 as 12. I've edited it to reflect the change.

Comment: Why is the desired result `[15,15,14,14,14,14,12]` rather than `[15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13]`?

Comment: It doesnt matter. the only thing that is required is to keep max of list minimum. If I do this incrementing one of the things at a time, It is gonna be quite inefficient for large numbers. @PM2Ring

Comment: Don't worry about efficiency before correctness. Premature optimization is the root of all evil :-)

Comment: @sureshvv I need it for 10 digit numbers, so I guess I'll have to worry about it ;)

Comment: @AyushGupta: Please see my new solution. It should _easily_ handle huge lists of 10 digit numbers efficiently.

Comment: @sureshvv: [To be more precise](https://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Donald_Knuth): "We should forget about small efficiencies, say about 97% of the time: premature optimization is the root of all evil. Yet we should not pass up our opportunities in that critical 3%". I guess this is one of those "critical 3%" cases. :)

Comment: @PM2Ring: Efficiency before correctness is always dubious. It seems Ayush just wants the max untouched. Unfortunately he was not able to express it clearly, hence the -4 on his question. It may be better to just allocate (max-i-1) to each member of the list until n is 0. See my updated answer

Comment: @sureshvv: Certainly, an algorithm needs to be correct, and a simple yet inefficient algorithm (like my first two solutions) can be handy to verify that a more efficient yet harder to understand algorithm performs correctly. Sure, it's a good idea to profile code on real data before engaging in optimizations; OTOH, using an O(n) algorithm is generally preferable to using an O(n^2) (or worse algorithm), especially when it's fairly clear that the O(n) algorithm will perform better than the simple but slow algorithm even with small n.

Comment: @sureshvv: Ayush doesn't actually say that the max must be untouched: he wants to "keep max of list minimum". Clearly, if `n` is large enough then the max of the list _will_ be modified.

Comment: @PM2Ring: Did u go thru my updated answer? Any comment?

Answer (score 1):

To update all minimums in a list to the next minimum you can use the following approach.

First determine the smallest value using Python's `min` function. Then calculate the second smallest by iterating over each of the values. It is then possible to use a list comprehension to update any value that is less than the second smallest value to be the second smallest value:

```
import sys

a = [15,15,14,12,10,10,10]
smallest = min(a)
second_smallest = sys.maxint        # Largest possible allowed integer

for x in a:
    if smallest < x < second_smallest:
        second_smallest = x

a[:] = [second_smallest if x < second_smallest else x for x in a]

print a
```

This displays the following:

```
[15, 15, 14, 12, 12, 12, 12]
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll leave my previous solutions here for "historical interest". Here's a *much* better solution. Not only is the code significantly shorter, it is much more efficient in both its calculations and the updating of the list.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Increment the minimum items of seq until sum(seq) has increased by n

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/32920173/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.10.04
'''

def increment_minimum(seq, n):
    ''' Increment the minimum items of seq until sum(seq) has increased by n
        seq must be sorted ascending.
    '''
    total = n
    for i, val in enumerate(seq):
        if i * val > total:
            break
        total += val
    else:
        i = len(seq)
        #print '*',

    val, rem = divmod(total, i)
    seq[:i] = [val] * (i - rem) + [val + 1] * rem


# Test
source_list = [10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18]
s = sum(source_list)
print 'org %s %d' % (source_list, s)

for n in range(0, 50):
    a = source_list[:]
    increment_minimum(a, n)
    newsum = sum(a)
    print '%2d: %s %d %d' % (n, a, newsum, newsum - (s + n))
```

**output**

```
org [10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 104
 0: [10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 104 0
 1: [10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 105 0
 2: [10, 11, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 106 0
 3: [11, 11, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 107 0
 4: [11, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 108 0
 5: [11, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 109 0
 6: [12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 18] 110 0
 7: [12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 18] 111 0
 8: [12, 12, 13, 13, 14, 15, 15, 18] 112 0
 9: [12, 13, 13, 13, 14, 15, 15, 18] 113 0
10: [13, 13, 13, 13, 14, 15, 15, 18] 114 0
11: [13, 13, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 18] 115 0
12: [13, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 18] 116 0
13: [13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 18] 117 0
14: [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 18] 118 0
15: [14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 18] 119 0
16: [14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 18] 120 0
17: [14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 18] 121 0
18: [14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 18] 122 0
19: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 18] 123 0
20: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 18] 124 0
21: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 18] 125 0
22: [15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 18] 126 0
23: [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18] 127 0
24: [15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18] 128 0
25: [15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18] 129 0
26: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 18] 130 0
27: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 18] 131 0
28: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 18] 132 0
29: [16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 18] 133 0
30: [16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18] 134 0
31: [16, 16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18] 135 0
32: [16, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18] 136 0
33: [17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18] 137 0
34: [17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18] 138 0
35: [17, 17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18] 139 0
36: [17, 17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18] 140 0
37: [17, 17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18] 141 0
38: [17, 17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18] 142 0
39: [17, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18] 143 0
40: [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18] 144 0
41: [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19] 145 0
42: [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19] 146 0
43: [18, 18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19] 147 0
44: [18, 18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19] 148 0
45: [18, 18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19] 149 0
46: [18, 18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19] 150 0
47: [18, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19] 151 0
48: [19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19] 152 0
49: [19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 19, 20] 153 0
```

---

Here's a simple way to increment the minimum item of a list by one until the list sum has been increased by the desired amount.

```
def increment_minimum(seq, n):
    ''' Increment the minimum item of seq n times '''
    for _ in range(n):
        m = min(seq)
        i = seq.index(m)
        seq[i] += 1
        print seq

a = [15, 15, 14, 12, 10, 10, 10]
print a, sum(a)

increment_minimum(a, 12)
print a, sum(a)
```

**output**

```
[15, 15, 14, 12, 10, 10, 10] 86
[15, 15, 14, 12, 11, 10, 10]
[15, 15, 14, 12, 11, 11, 10]
[15, 15, 14, 12, 11, 11, 11]
[15, 15, 14, 12, 12, 11, 11]
[15, 15, 14, 12, 12, 12, 11]
[15, 15, 14, 12, 12, 12, 12]
[15, 15, 14, 13, 12, 12, 12]
[15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12]
[15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 13, 12]
[15, 15, 14, 13, 13, 13, 13]
[15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 13]
[15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13]
[15, 15, 14, 14, 14, 13, 13] 98
```

This function will perform correctly even if `seq` is not sorted, and it doesn't disturb the ordering of items in `seq` . It's not very efficient, but it may be adequate when `seq` is short and `n` is small.

A more efficient approach is to use a [heap queue](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html):

```
def increment_minimum(seq, n):
    ''' Increment the minimum item of seq n times '''
    #Build heap from seq
    heap = seq[:]
    heapq.heapify(heap)

    for _ in range(n):
        #Increment the smallest item on the heap
        m = heapq.heappop(heap)
        heapq.heappush(heap, m + 1)

    #Copy heap items back to seq
    for i in range(len(seq)):
        seq[-1-i] = heapq.heappop(heap)
```

This version also handles unsorted input, but the updated list will always be sorted, due to the way the heap queue works.

This function is much more efficient than the previous version when `seq` contains many items, although if you intend to call it many times on the same list then it would be better to maintain the heap externally rather than rebuilding it in the function on each call. However, this version is still not particularly efficient when `n` is large. To handle large `n` more efficiently, I suspect that [itertools.groupby](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html?itertools.groupby#itertools.groupby) would be useful.

---

Here's a version that should be more efficient, especially if `n` is large enough to increase all items in the list to be >= the current maximum.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

''' Increment the minimum items of seq until sum(seq) has increased by n

    From http://stackoverflow.com/q/32920173/4014959

    Written by PM 2Ring 2015.10.03
'''

from itertools import groupby

def increment_minimum(seq, n):
    ''' Increment the minimum items of seq
        until sum(seq) has increased by n

        seq must be sorted ascending.
    '''
    #Check if n is large enough to make all items 
    # >= the current max.
    newsum = n + sum(seq)
    seqlen = len(seq)
    if newsum >= seq[-1] * seqlen:
        v, r = divmod(newsum, seqlen)
        seq[:] = [v] * (seqlen - r) + [v+1] * r
        return

    #Otherwise, successively increment the groups of smallest items
    #to the value of the next smallest items

    #Split items into groups of equal value
    a = [(len(list(g)), v) for v, g in groupby(seq)]
    k = 0
    for i in range(len(a) - 1):
        #Get the cumulative number of group items
        k += a[i][0]

        #Get the difference in value between this group & the next smallest 
        v = a[i+1][1] - a[i][1]

        #Increment the k smallest items by (at most) v
        for j in range(k-1, -1, -1):
            if v <= n:
                seq[j] += v
                n -= v
            else:
                seq[j] += n
                return


# Test
source_list = [10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16]
s = sum(source_list)

for n in range(30):
    a = source_list[:]
    increment_minimum(a, n)
    print '%2d: %s %s' % (n, a, sum(a) == s + n)
```

**output**

```
 0: [10, 10, 10, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 1: [10, 10, 11, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 2: [10, 10, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 3: [10, 11, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 4: [10, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 5: [11, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 6: [12, 12, 12, 12, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 7: [12, 12, 12, 13, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 8: [12, 12, 12, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
 9: [12, 12, 13, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
10: [12, 12, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
11: [12, 13, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
12: [12, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
13: [13, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
14: [14, 14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 16] True
15: [14, 14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 16] True
16: [14, 14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16] True
17: [14, 14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16] True
18: [14, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16] True
19: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16] True
20: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16] True
21: [15, 15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16] True
22: [15, 15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16] True
23: [15, 15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16] True
24: [15, 15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16] True
25: [15, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16] True
26: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16] True
27: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17] True
28: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17] True
29: [16, 16, 16, 16, 16, 17, 17, 17] True
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
def distribute(l, n):
    m = max(l) - 1
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if not n:
            break
        incr = min(m - l[i], n)
        if incr > 0:
            l[i] += incr
            n -= incr

a = [15, 15, 14, 12, 10, 10, 10]
distribute(a, 12)
print a
```

Comment: This answer sort-of works for small `n`: it doesn't attempt to focus the increments on the smaller items in the list, but that _may_ be ok for the OP's purpose. However, it fails for larger `n`, eg with the example list it fails for `n>14`.